# Vim highlight specially plugin syntax

Tags: vim, editor

For example , i use this command to highlight standard Statement:

`hi Statement term=bold ctermfg=245 gui=bold guifg=#969896`

But my plugin also change color,so i try to get syntax attritube

for example in c code

"if" or "while" is "cCondtional->Statement"

and my NERDTree menu is:

"NERDTreeCWD->Statement"

How can i highlight for "cCondtional->Statement" or "NERDTreeCWD->Statement"?

I try to set:

`hi NERDTreeCWD->Statement term=bold ctermfg=245 gui=bold guifg=#969896`

But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NERDTreeCWD->Statement` means that the `NERDTreeCWD` highlight group is *linked to* the default `Statement` group, via the `:hi link NERDTreeCWD Statement` command. If I understand you right, you want to change both independently, i.e. break the link. For that, you just need to redefine it:

```
hi NERDTreeCWD term=bold ctermfg=245 gui=bold guifg=#969896
```

You can put this into your `~/.vimrc`; (syntax and normal) plugins are supposed to use `:hi default`, which will not override your definitions.